# Updation of product description from admin panel is not showing up in storefront in magento2?

Tags: magento2, products, admin-panel, catalog-rules

We tried to update product description form admin-panel, but it's not reflecting in the storefront.

Tried with reindexing, cache flush commands. It did not work.

Comment: Did you try using incognito mode?

Comment: Yes. Tried with incognito.Also,I tried by giving cache clear from admin panel and command line as well

Comment: did you run all these commands: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php bin/magento cache:clean` and  `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Yes. i ran the above commands

Comment: Do you have different store views?

Comment: @sahana, do the changes in appropriate store view scope

Comment: We have enabled single store view mode

Comment: @sahana it is strange, get a link to the page

Answer (score 4):

Can you retouch the product attributes scopes and then try one?

Eg: For Description attributes, If the scope is **store view** then change it to **global** -> save -> again change it to **store view** and save it.

It worked for me.

Comment: This was worked for me, thanks a lot! pull out my hair to resolve this )